# Android: isometric view in OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, openstreetmap, isometric

I am developing an Android app with OpenStreetMap (OSM). I want isometric view in map. Is it possible to get isometric view in OpenStreetMap? Any clue or hint is highly appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but there is no ready to use framework esp. for Android.
[Here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM2World/Maps) is what the guys of http://maps.osm2world.org did to realize it.

**Software used to create the isometric tiles**

- Mapsplit splits OSM extracts into data tiles
- OSM2World creates the 3D models and renders them using OpenGL to create PNGs
  Xvfb functions as an X server when working with OpenGL
- png_tilegen splits OSM2World's PNG output into tile-sized images